# Why my seaborn graph does not show x-axis values

Tags: seaborn

I would like to plot the predicted bitcoin prices of a ML model that I am building. Here is the code:

```
ax = sns.lineplot(x=original.index, y=original[0], label="Test Data", color='royalblue')
ax = sns.lineplot(x=predictions.index, y=predictions[0], label="Prediction", color='tomato')
ax.set_title('Bitcoin price', size = 14, fontweight='bold')
ax.set_xlabel("Days", size = 14)
ax.set_ylabel("Cost (USD)", size = 14)
ax.set_xticklabels('', size=10)
```

[image]

On the *x* axis, there should be around 240 points (days), which I suspecting to prevent them to be displayed (too much days to display), so is there a way to display just a few of the days (Like every 30 days or so) ?

Comment: Simply remove x.set_xticklabels('', size=10).

Comment: @DavidM. Awesome, thanks a lot !

Comment: To change the tick label size: `ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelsize=10)`